# Симуляция зажатия кнопки. Python

Tags: python

Я пишу небольшой макрос для игры который будет постоянно зажимать клавишу w.
Можно конечно сделать что то типо этого:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press('w')
```

Но проблема в том, что он не симулирует нажатие кнопки, а лишь *кликает на неё*, что не подходит. Как можно симулировать зажатие кнопки?
Самое интересное, что нужно именно симулировать нажатия.

Comment: Подскажите, какая ОС у Вас стоит?

Comment: Windows. Ещё я щяс немного изменю вопрос.

Comment: Пробовали сделать таким образом? `keyboard.press('w') keyboard.release('w')`? Вообще под win можно использовать pywin.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Такое не работает, c pywin ом в текстовый блокнот пишется, а вот игра не воспринимает.

Comment: Есть модуль pykeyboard, входит в PyUserInput . Попробуйте, должно подойти.

Comment: Подходит только для игры у которой нет *защиты*. Проблема в том что мне нужно именно симулировать нажатие. @Ghostik2005